# Seg fault while calling glfwSwapBuffers

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, glfw

It seems that I am having a seg fault while using GLFW and OpenGL on ArchLinux, DWM (fully updated and patched).

I retraced the code and it is having the segFault in the `glfwSwapBuffers(window)`.

Here is my code :

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "gui/window.h"

int main(int, char**) {
    Window window("Test GL", 800, 600);

    if(!window.hasCorrectlyLoaded()) {
        return 1;
    }

    while (!window.shouldClose())
    {
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        window.pollEvents();
    }
}
```

window.h

```cpp
#ifndef __WINDOW_H__
#define __WINDOW_H__

#include <string>
#include <glad/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class Window {
private:
    GLFWwindow *window;
    bool correctlyLoaded;

public:
    Window(const std::string&, int, int);
    ~Window();

    const bool hasCorrectlyLoaded();
    const bool shouldClose();

    const void pollEvents();
};

#endif // __WINDOW_H__
```

window.cpp

```cpp
#include "window.h"
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>

Window::Window(const std::string& title, int width, int height)
{
    correctlyLoaded = false;
    if(!glfwInit()) {
        spdlog::default_logger()->critical("Could not load GLFW");
        return;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window)
    {
        spdlog::default_logger()->critical("Failed to create GLFW window !");
        return;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        spdlog::default_logger()->critical("Failed to load OpenGL !");
        return;
    }

    spdlog::default_logger()->info("Loaded OpenGL {}", glfwGetVersionString());
    
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    correctlyLoaded = true;
}

const void Window::pollEvents()
{
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents(); //<- Seg fault here
}

Window::~Window()
{
    glfwTerminate();
}

const bool Window::hasCorrectlyLoaded()
{
    return correctlyLoaded;
}

const bool Window::shouldClose()
{
    return glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
}
```

While further researching, I stumbled upon an answer that told me to set the `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_API)` window hint but I still got a segfault, but at a different place :

GLFW source code

```cpp
GLFWAPI void glfwSwapBuffers(GLFWwindow* handle)
{
    _GLFWwindow* window = (_GLFWwindow*) handle;
    assert(window != NULL);

    _GLFW_REQUIRE_INIT();

    if (window->context.client == GLFW_NO_API)
    {
        _glfwInputError(GLFW_NO_WINDOW_CONTEXT,
                        "Cannot swap buffers of a window that has no OpenGL or OpenGL ES context"); //<- Seg fault without window hint
        return;
    }

    window->context.swapBuffers(window); //<- Seg fault with window hint
}
```

Here is the output I get from the logging :

```
[2022-05-24 20:01:04.252] [info] Loaded OpenGL 3.4.0 X11 GLX Null EGL OSMesa monotonic
[1]    432406 segmentation fault (core dumped)  /home/lygaen/code/testgl/build/testgl
```

Comment: You never store your `GLFWwindow` handle in your `Window` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem occurs in Window.cpp, at this line:

```
//...
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr); //<---
if (!window)
{
//...
```

You've redeclared `window` as a local variable to this constructor, and as a result, the pointer never escapes the constructor, and is dangled.

A good habit when trying to assign class members is to use the `this` keyword. It is often redundant, but it does help indicate intent. So the code should be changed to this:

```
//...
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);

this->window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr); //<---
if (!this->window)
{
//...
```

If your style guidelines don't permit it, you can omit the `this->`; the only important part is that you're not declaring an entirely new variable that's shadowing the class member.